# Database Goes To "Suspect Mode" But DBCC CHECKDB Result is Success

Tags: sql-server

I have this question. If database goes into "Suspect  Mode" but when I check it in "Emergency Mode" with the "DBCC CHECKDB" command, the result is successful. It means that the data page files are correct or maybe some of them are damaged?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pages that caused the database to be marked suspect may no longer matter - for example, if they have been deallocated.

You can determine whether this is the case by checking the `event_type` column of [`msdb.dbo.suspect_pages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/suspect-pages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

You may also want to look through the SQL error log for any relevant messages.

If everything is ok (and you have verified that recent backups are available and not about to be deleted, just in case) you can go through [repair](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-emergency-mode-repair-the-very-very-last-resort/).

You may also want to turn on [checksum page verification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/policy-based-management/set-the-page-verify-database-option-to-checksum?view=sql-server-ver16) if it is not currently set.

Answer (score 0):

Suspect mode can occurs by various reasons few are mention below.

- System Issues
- Transaction Log File is Missing
- SQL Server Crash
- Database Files are inaccessible
- SQL Server Database Operation Failures
- Due to Improper shut down of SQL Server System
- Due to Sudden Power Outage
- Low Disk Space Issues
- Hardware Failure

In my experience Emergency Mode with the "DBCC CHECKDB" command is the best practice to recover database from suspect mode but sometimes "DBCC CHECKDB WITH REPAIR ALLOW DATA LOSS" can be the reason of data loss.

As an answer - It means that the data page files are correct or maybe some of them are damaged?
Please look into you log file to verify the cause.

Thanks :)